# Windows Phone 8 Save Image from byte[]

Tags: c#, image, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have created a basic steganography application for windows phone 8 that works fine on the emulator but I get an error when using a device. With the emulator I can save a byte[] as an image as shown below:

```
byteArrayTextandImage = EncodeText(byteArrayInputImageEncode,byteArrayInputText, 4096);
using (var s = new MemoryStream())
{
    Picture pic = library.SavePicture(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), byteArrayTextandImage);
}
```

I tried to get around it by using a WritableBitmap as shown below:

```
using (var s = new MemoryStream())
{
    WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapSource)bmp);
    wb.SaveJpeg(s, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight, 0, 72);
    s.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var pic = library.SavePicture(Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg", s);
    MessageBox.Show(pic.Name);
}
```

however this is modifying the image and removing the text I had encoded within it. Has anybody encountered a problem like this before? Why would the emulator work fine but not on a device? I have checked the manifest and I have the necessary capabilities checked.

Thanks for any help anybody can provide.

Comment: I/O permissions OK? Check if they are checked in config file.

Comment: Can you share the error?

Comment: How do you embed your secret? You save the image in jpg format, which compresses the image and may destroy the secret. Have you tried a different format, such as png, or bmp?

Comment: I don't want to save as a Jpeg, I tried the second option after the first one failed on my device. WriteableBitmap only has SaveJpeg on Windows Phone 8. The first code box shows how it works on my emulator without losing the secret, this is how I want it to work, however when I run the same code on a device I get System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range when I call library.SavePicture. Any ideas as to why? I have checked ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO in the manifest